# Trying to Net::SFTP download but get Errno::EACCES: Permission denied - Directory I'm copying to

Tags: ruby, net-sftp

I'm trying to copy a file from a Unix box to my local desktop but I'm getting the error: `Errno::EACCES: Permission denied - C:\Users\MyUser\Desktop`

```
require 'net/sftp'
Net::SFTP.start(unixBox, user, :password => password) do |sftp|
  sftp.download!(filePathOnUnixBox, 'C:\Users\MyUser\Desktop')
end
```

**My Desktop**: Windows 7

ruby 1.8.7 (2010-12-23 patchlevel 330) [i386-mingw32]

net-sftp (2.1.1)

**Unix box:** SunOS

UPDATE: Looks like you have to specify the filename in your TO file path so `C:\Users\MyUser\Desktop` becomes `C:\Users\MyUser\Desktop\fileNameIWant.ext`

Comment: can you write to that path with a simple `File.write`?

Comment: I was able to with `File.open("C:\\Users\\MyUser\\Desktop\\test.txt", 'w+') do |x|
x.write("hello")
end`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you have to specify the filename in your TO file path so `C:\Users\MyUser\Desktop` becomes `C:\Users\MyUser\Desktop\fileNameIWant.ext`

Before I was only specifying the path but not the file name.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the user that's running the ruby script does not have permission to write to your HDD. Maybe `MyUser` is not the user that's executing the script.

EDIT:

Forgot to mention, you could try and escape the windows backslashes. Try:

```
C:\\Users\\MyUser\\Desktop
```

as the local path

Comment: I'm running the ruby script with the same user that is on the desktop, its not an admin account though.

Comment: I've tried both `'C:\Users\MyUser\Desktop'` and `"C:\\Users\\MyUser\\Desktop"`.  On a side note should I have something like `"C:\\Users\\MyUser\\Desktop\\TheFileName.ext"` instead of the folder only?

Comment: yeah looking at the docs, it does look like you need the filename. That would explain the permission denied error, too. You can't write over a folder.

Comment: Oh, great. I didn't know that. I use Net::SFTP a lot but never actually downloaded an entire file, only certain bits (mostly logs)

Comment: Sweet that fixed my problem, kch do you want to answer the question so I can checkmark it?

Comment: It's not necessary to use backslashes for DOS/Windows filenames. Ruby, like Perl and many other languages, is smart enough to recognize it's running on Windows and needs to reverse the delimiters, and does it automatically. That lets us use forward slashes always.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do to avoid madness, is stop using backslashes in Windows filenames when using Ruby. Per the [IO documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/IO.html):

> Ruby will convert pathnames between different operating system conventions if possible. For instance, on a Windows system the filename "/gumby/ruby/test.rb" will be opened as "\gumby\ruby\test.rb". [...]

Comment: Madness? this is Ruby!  This is something I will do from now on, it will make paths easier to understand/type.